# Error al pasar a mayúsculas

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Estoy usando angular t engo el siguiente fichero test.ts

```
interface SimulationParameters {
  name: string;
};

constructor() {
 this.simulation = {name: ''}
}

this.aggregationService.loadSimulation(id, simulationId).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.simulation.name = response.description.split('/')
```

Si pongo lo siguiente funciona:

```
{{'testing' | uppercase}}
```

pero si pongo lo sgte no funciona, si elimino el uppercase si veo el valor:

```
{{simulation.name | uppercase}}
```

El error que obtengo es:

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Testing' for pipe 'UpperCasePipe'
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ponernos un poco más en contexto?, yo he hecho lo que tu dices creando un objeto simulation con atributo name, y he hecho ese mismo ejemplo y me lo ha pintado sin ningún problema, ¿puedes ponernos más código?

Comment: @chikebox añadido más código

Comment: ¿puede ser que tu problema este en `this.simulation.name = response.description.split('/')`?, lo digo porque ahí simulation.name es un array de strings, no un string, declara el atributo simulacion así: 

`simulacion: string;` a ver si te da algún error de compilación o algo

Comment: efectivamente, ese era mi error, gracias

Comment: te recomiendo que añadas la respuesta a la pregunta con tu solución y te marques a tí mismo como mejor respuesta, por si alguien busca algo parecido que tenga un sitio donde encontrar la respuesta.